# ElasticSearch: Secondary indecies on field values using Java-API

Tags: java, performance, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm considering to use ElasticSearch as a search engine for large objects. There are about 500 millions objects on a single machine. For far is Elasticsearch a good solution for executing advanced queries. But a have the problem that i did find any technique to create secondary index on the document fields. Is in elasticsearch a possibility to create a secondary indecies like in MySQL on columns? Or are there any other technologies implemented to accelerate searches on field values? I'm using an single server enviroment and I have to store about 300 fields per row/object. At the moment there are about 500 million object in my database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize in advance it I don't understand the question.  Elasticsearch is itself an index based technology (it's built on top of Lucene which is a build for index based search).  You put documents into Elasticsearch and the individual fields on those documents are indexed and searchable.  You should not have to worry about creating secondary indexes; the fields will be indexed by default (in most cases).

One of the differences between Elasticsearch and Solr is that in Solr, you have to specify a schema defining what the fields are on the documents and whether that field will be indexed (available to search against), stored (available as the result of a search) or both.  Elasticsearch does not require an upfront schema, and in lieu of specific mappings for fields, then reasonable defaults are used instead.  I believe that the core fields (string, number, etc..._) are indexed by default, meaning they are available to search against.

Now in your case, you have a document with a lot of fields on it.  You will probably need to tweak the mappings a bit to only index the fields that you know you might search against.  If you index too much, the size of the index itself will balloon and will not be as fast as if you had a trim index of only the fields you know you will search against.  Also, Lucene loads parts of the index into memory to really enable fast searches.  With a bloated index, you won't be able to keep as much stuff in memory and your searches will suffer as a result.  You should look at the [Mappings API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/) and the [Core Types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/) section for more info on how to do this.

Comment: It seems to be the right think i intended to do. I overread the mapping stuff because of the confusion about index (in elasticsearch context) and the index in relational databases. Settign for properties indexed = "analyzed" seems to be the right approach. However i still stuck in the problem described above. After some reasearches i found a way to change the mapping but it seems not effecting at all and i have no idea what im doing wrong. Can anybody help me?